# How to decrease size of an multiple images in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload multiple images to server using Retrofit, While I upload small images no problem at all but if I upload large images it's get timeout error. Here is my code

```
  File file1 = new File(getRealPathFromDocumentUri(this, selected.get(0)));
  File file2 = new File(getRealPathFromDocumentUri(this, selected.get(1)));
  RequestBody reqFile1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file1);
  RequestBody reqFile2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file2);
  MultipartBody.Part body1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image1", file1.getName(), reqFile1);
  MultipartBody.Part body2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image2", file1.getName(), reqFile2);

    RequestBody premium1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), premium);
    RequestBody featured1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), featured);


    Call<ResponseBody> call = api.getPostedResult(premium1, featured1, body1, body2);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            //  pb.dismiss();utils
            utils.dismissProgress();
            if (response.code() == 200) {


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your AD Have been Posted Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = null;
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LandingPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            //
            utils.dismissProgress();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

and I'm getting file path using my List selected and sending it to below code, Please help me with this, I  want to know how to decrease image size and send it to server in Multipart.body

```
     public static String getRealPathFromDocumentUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String filePath = "";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(uri.toString());
    if (!m.find()) {
        //    Log.e(ImageConverter.class.getSimpleName(), "ID for requested image not found: " + uri.toString());
        return filePath;
    }
    String imgId = m.group();

    String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, sel, new String[]{imgId}, null);

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();

    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: You should leave it to the user I think. For example, in many applications the maximum file size to be uploaded is 3MB to 5MB. You might consider putting some restriction in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decrease image size, you need to follow some few step.

First, you need to get BitMap from your original image URL

Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);

second, scaled  the Bitmap according to your option

scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

then save the image to a temp file and use this URL for upload.

if you want then use this open Library (https://github.com/amanjeetsingh150/ImageZipper)